# Consulta SQL não retorna itens esperados

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho duas tabelas chamadas **Protocolo** e **Analise** com um relacionamento 1:n, um **Protocolo** pode ter várias **Análises**, sendo que Protocolo tem chave primária composta. Preciso escrever um SQL que me retorne os Protocolos que não possuem nenhuma Análise e os Protocolos que possuem pelo menos uma Análise. Tentei escrever alguns, mas sem sucesso, as consultas não retornam os itens esperados, ou não retornam nada

```
|PROTOCOLO      |         |ANALISE              |
|prefixo PK     |         |idanalise PK         |
|numero  PK     |         |prefixo FK           |
|ano     PK     |         |numero  FK           |
|// OUTROS ATTRS|         |ano     FK           |
                          |// OUTROS ATRIBUTOS  |
```

**SQL que eu tentei fazer para Protocolos sem nenhuma análise**

```
SELECT * FROM protocolo p WHERE p.prefixo 
NOT IN (SELECT a.protocolo_prefixo 
FROM analise a) 
AND p.numero NOT IN (SELECT a.protocolo_numero 
FROM analise a) 
AND p.ano NOT IN (SELECT a.protocolo_ano 
FROM analise a)
```

**SQL que eu tentei fazer para protocolos com pelo menos 1 análise**

```
SELECT * FROM protocolo p WHERE p.prefixo 
IN (SELECT a.protocolo_prefixo 
FROM analise a) 
AND p.numero IN (SELECT a.protocolo_numero 
FROM analise a) 
AND p.ano IN (SELECT a.protocolo_ano 
FROM analise a)
```

Comment: Fiz um exemplo online para usar de base para resolver o problema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bbabe/13

Comment: @David, obrigada pela ajuda, já consegui resolver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocolos sem nenhuma análise:

```
SELECT * FROM protocolo WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM analise WHERE protocolo.prefixo = analise.prefixo AND protocolo.numero = analise.numero AND protocolo.ano = analise.ano);
```

ou ainda:

```
SELECT protocolo.* FROM protocolo LEFT OUTER JOIN analise ON (protocolo.prefixo = analise.prefixo AND protocolo.numero = analise.numero AND protocolo.ano = analise.ano) WHERE analise.prefixo IS NULL;
```

Para saber quais protocolos possuem pelo menos uma análise basta fazer um INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT protocolo.* FROM protocolo INNER JOIN analise ON (protocolo.prefixo = analise.prefixo AND protocolo.numero = analise.numero AND protocolo.ano = analise.ano);
```

Agora em suas queries você não utiliza a tabela analise a que se refere no início de sua questão.

Comment: Verdade, tava mexendo em umas coisas aqui e fiz confusão com o nome das tabelas na hora de escrever a consulta aqui, já editei a questão

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e deu certo, obrigada!

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário